# Coordinate overlapping components to scale together

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Attempting to create a higher-order component with two components that scale together.

The higher-order component is set up as so:

```
<>
    <Component 1/>
    <Component 2/>
</>
```

The css for Component 1:

```
{ 
  height: 735px;
  background-image: url(url);
}
```

and for Component 2:

```
{
  height: 286px;
  margin: -150px auto 0;
  width: 1305px;
}
```

This is the initial render:

[image]

This is the render after viewport is shrunk:

[image]

Component 1 shrinks, while Component 2 stays in the position.

Is there a way to have them scale together and maintain relative position?

I've tried using `Grid` from `@material-ui` but have had no luck.

Should I look into using `grid` layout in css, or would it be the same as using `Grid` from `@material-ui`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I understand it you want the components to remain proportional but have the second one remain fixed relative to the first? Here's a possibility if you want to go the usual CSS way:

If you want the content to remain proportional but still scale and overlap, you can use some positioning techniques combined with percentage values on your divs and a flexbox to base the percentages on.

I don't know what you're putting in the components so I just used images with `object-fit` so you'll need to tailor it to whatever you're putting in there.

(you can ignore the background and outline on the flex container, that's jut to save my eyes some strain ;) )

Let me know if that helps!

```css
.components {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  flex: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 90vh;
  width: auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  outline: 1px solid grey;
}

.c1 {
  height: 70%;
  width: 90%;
  background-image: url(url);
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.c2 {
  height: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 55%;
  left: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#img1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#img2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="components">
  <div class="c1"><img id="img1" src="https://i.imgur.com/Hrbzpp9.jpeg">
    <div class="c2"><img id="img2" src="https://i.imgur.com/8jhZLa1.jpeg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  

In my case, adding `background-size: cover;` to `Component 1` seems to have fixed the issue.

But your solution seems like it'd be more general.